# Extjs not display column in graph when use with bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I have problem when i render graph extjs to my page that use bootstrap .

how ever,it work as simple when render to page that no bootstrap included.does it have any solution ? Please Help. Thank in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need this css rule:

```
[hidden], template { display:block }
```

cause ExtJS uses the `hidden=false` to indicate that something isn't hidden (like the graph columns) and bootstrap wants to display everything with a hidden property, no matter what value, as hidden.